# Html Table width automatically expands

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-tables

My table width automatically expands beyond div width.

I searched a long time but I can't find any answer.

I don't know where the issue went wrong too.

So please help after see the below images.

[image: Style]

other Image:

[image: tag]

Comment: Try setting a position on the elements

Comment: @adeneo : please explain briefly what is position in elements

Comment: so your using a fixed div width and a dynamic table width?

Comment: No,i m not using fixed div width too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `table-layout:fixed;` Table-layout by default is auto so as your contents increases your table also increases.

```
table{
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: I tried giving this table-layout: fixed in table tag. Not Working

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged 'JQuery'. Are you using some scripts on that page? Could some of them be connected with the table? 
And also would be nice if you show us any examples.

Comment: Agree with you. Sorry, dont have enought reputation, but still want to help.